# How to disable textarea matInput resizing?

Tags: css, angular-material

With pure textarea i can disable resizing with  `textarea {resize: none;}` But with  textarea matInput it doesn't work. Is it possible to disable resizing for Angular Material textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding style="resize: none;" on html code?

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field style="border: 1px solid black">
    <textarea style="resize: none;" matInput>can NOT resize</textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

[image]

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field style="border: 1px solid black">
    <textarea matInput>can resize</textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

[image]